# What's the Use of azure build definition.Can I create azure build definition from TFS?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cloud-services, build-definition

I have my source code on TFS 2012.I explored azure build definition which is available with visual studio online which uses the cloud service.Is it possible to to create azure build definition in TFS 2012?

Comment: can you explain what you want to do ? what kind of application you want to deploy, and what kind of services you want to use in Azure (only cloud service or other) ?

Comment: The main problem is I am using TFS 2012 that I cant Upgrade.I want analyse my project with Sonarqube. but its not possible with TFS 2012.so I am just exploring weather  it is possible to keep my code on TFS 2012 and Use some azure build process so that I can use it for Sonarqube integration.

Comment: Did you saw this post : http://mydevtalks.blogspot.com/2015/01/install-configure-sonar-with-tfs-2012.html ? (it's not about Azure / VSTS, but it explains how to use Sonar with TFS 2012)

Comment: Thanks for update .I have seen but it seems some kind of hack i'll try.